# Cycle around the "end" of workspaces in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have a typical Gnome setup, in which i can move/switch between workspaces, by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>‹or›</kbd>arrow. But when i'm in workspace 1, hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>‹</kbd> has no effect, and similarly for my maximum workspace (typically 4).

Is there any way I can have this cycle around, so that hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>›</kbd> in workspace 4 will bring me back around to 1?

Comment: It depends on the windows manager you're using. Ubuntu -> compiz, Gnome2 -> Metacity, Gnome3 -> Gnome Shell (Mutter).

Comment: You can use [workspace switch wraparound](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1116/workspace-switch-wraparound/) to do this task.

Answer (score 17):

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Launch Compiz Config from *System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager*.
3. Navigate to *Desktop Wall -> Viewport Switching* and check the *Allow Wrap-Around* checkbutton:

   [image]

   [image]